# WCDMA , 8PSK signal, 3 G , user end sensitivity, required SNR

Tags: rf, wireless, dsp

Does anyone know how the User End receiver sensitivity for a 3G WCDMA, 8 PSK signal is calculated? and what is the typical SNR required to detect the signal?

Comment: 12 dB minimum https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281373723_PERFORMANCE_OF_8-PSK_MODULATION_SCHEME_USING_RAYLEIGH_FADING_CHANNEL_FOR_WCDMA_SYSTEM but then Ricean fading occurs often and non-ideal for motion.

Comment: so in the 3 GPP standard if sensitivity is specified as -106.7 dBm, which receiver NF is assumed and what is the number assumed for implementation loss?

Comment: It is always a slope of BER vs SNR or RSSI. NF depends on product